# I have an AlertDialog with 100 buttons and it appears with 400ms delay when I call show() for the first time

Tags: android, optimization, drawing, android-alertdialog

When I call `dialog.show()` later, it appears very fast. Seems like Android UI uses some sort of cache. How to force Android create this cache in the background?

`dialogLaout.invalidate` didn't help

`buildDrawingCache()` is depricated and seems to be turned off anyway

Comment: Can you make it of 0 size, "show" it, then hide it and change its size?

Comment: `When I call dialog.show() later, ..` ? Later then what? And where is this about?